# Why does my cosine of 90 degree shows as -4.371139E-08 in output

Tags: c#, math, trigonometry, radians

[This is the code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O4YYY.png)

[This is the Output I am getting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4ZpuR.png)

```
Console.Write("Enter angle in degrees: ");

// angle == 90
float angle = float.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
float radian = angle * (MathF.PI / 180);

Console.WriteLine("Sine is " + MathF.Sin(radian) );

// Expected "Consine is 0"
// Actual   "Cosine is -4.371139e-08"
Console.WriteLine("Cosine is " + MathF.Cos(radian));
```

Why do I have `-4.371139e-08` instead of `0`?

Comment: Welcome! Please post the code here!

Comment: -0.00000004371139 is close to 0 so where is the problem ? ... prolly `MathF.PI` is also not a  real PI value - that's why

Comment: [just format it to show only few numbers after decimal point and this should be ok](https://dotnetfiddle.net/gux5vZ)

Answer (score 2):

Let's do a simple math:

```
cos(pi/2 + x) = -sin(x) = - x + x^3/3! - x^5/5! + ... ~ -x # for small x
```

In our case:

```
90 * (MathF.PI / 180) == 1.5707963705062866 
PI / 2                == 1.5707963267948966... # note the difference
```

So

```
90 * (MathF.PI / 180) == PI / 2 + 4.371139006309477E-08
```

That's why `MathF.Cos(90 * (MathF.PI / 180))` expected to be `-4.371139006309477E-08`, not `0`.